# Finding the radius, distance of the center of circle inscribed in the square

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

I am trying to solve this question but can't figure out the last part. I was able to get answers for part A and B but i don't know how to approach/solve part C. Any help will be appreciated.

The square is bounded by the lines

```
 x = 1, y = 1, x = -1, y = -1
```

The circle inscribed in the square is the unit

```
x^2 + y^2 = 1
```

Let C be the circle in the upper right hand corner, inscribed in the region bounded by the lines x = 1, y = 1, and the unit circle.

a) If r is the radius of C, find the center of C in terms of r.

```
The answer to part a is: (1-r) (1-r)
```

b) Find the distance of the center of C to (0,0) in terms of r.

```
Using Distance Formula sqrt((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2)
We get the following answer: sqrt(2 (-1 + r)^2)
```

c) Find r using a) and b) or with some other method?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates are right, and therefore the distance to the origin is $\sqrt{2(1-r)^2}$, which is $\sqrt{2}(1-r)$, since $r\lt 1$.  But this distance is clearly $1+r$. It follows that
$$\sqrt{2}(1-r)=1+r.$$
This is a linear equation in $r$. Solve, and perhaps simplify.